# Wordpress: Change Post Featured Image alt tags to the given alt tag while uploading

Tags: php, wordpress

I am giving alt tags for an image while uploading, but it is not taking the given image alt tags , it shows blank

i tried to add this filter but still not working

```
/* Register callback function for post_thumbnail_html filter hook */
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'meks_post_thumbnail_alt_change', 10, 5 );

/* Function which will replace alt atribute to post title */
function meks_post_thumbnail_alt_change( $html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr ) {

    $post_title = get_the_title();
    $html = preg_replace( '/(alt=")(.*?)(")/i', '$1'.esc_attr( $post_title ).'$3', $html );

    return $html;

}
```

The post content is displayed from `loop-single.php` file

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyten' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

How to use those alt tags for my post featured image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found out the error , it seems previous developer added the image manually to the post and featured image was also set . so i got confused.

i simply put the alt text in edit mode of the post directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for me :)

```
function change_post_thumbnail_html($html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr) {
    $id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, $size); 
    $alt = get_the_title($id); // gets the post thumbnail title
    $class = $attr['class'];
    $html = '<img src="' . $src[0] . '" alt="' . $alt . '" class="' . $class . '" />';
    return $html;
}
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', 'change_post_thumbnail_html', 99, 5);
```

Comment: @mahethekiller did you add this code in `functions.php` ? and try adding `die('call');` before `return $html` to check this filter is working or not for featured image ?>